# Unresolved reference while trying to use a xml id in kotlin file

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to build a to-do app using **Android Studio** in `Kotlin`.
When I am trying to use an id `tvTodoTitle` ,it says unresolved reference same goes for `cbDone` id.

What should I do to solve the error?

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvTodoItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnAddTodo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etTodoTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Todo Title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnAddTodo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddTodo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Todo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnDeleteTodo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDeleteTodo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete Todo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**item_todo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:paddingStart ="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTodoTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sample"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cbDone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this the **todoAdapter.kt** file

```
package com.mohan.project

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class TodoAdapter
    (private val todos:MutableList<Todo>): RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>()
{
    class TodoViewHolder(itemview: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemview)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {
return TodoViewHolder(
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
        R.layout.item_todo,
        parent,
        false
    )
)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return todos.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val curTodo=todos[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            tvTodoTitle.text = curTodo.title
            cbDone.isChecked= curtodo.isChecked
        }
    }
}
```

In the `onBindViewHolder` when I'm trying to use **tvTodoTitle** it says unresolved reference.